# Set Finatra HTTP request timeout

Tags: scala, finatra

Is it possible to set HTTP request-response timeout in a Finatra server?

The http controller callback typically returns a Future, that once resolved the response is transmitted. I would like to define, within Finatra, how long the server should wait before returning a 500 or 400 response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the `HttpServer` and define your own timeout

```
    trait CustomServer extends HttpServer with Tls {
```

then you overwrite the `configureHttpServer` method and you define timeout, requests sites, and other attributes

```
  override def configureHttpServer(server: Http.Server): Http.Server = {
    server.withAdmissionControl.concurrencyLimit(maxConcurrentRequests = 2000, maxWaiters = 0)
      .withResponseClassifier(HttpResponseClassifier.ServerErrorsAsFailures)
      .withMaxRequestSize(StorageUnit.fromMegabytes(200))
      .withRequestTimeout(50.seconds)
  }
```

Or, a more minimal example in your class that extends `Http.Server`:

```
      override protected def configureHttpServer(server: Http.Server): Http.Server = {
        super.configureHttpServer(server.withRequestTimeout(50.seconds))
      }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks @lssilva

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for [Future.within](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/com/twitter/util/Future.html#within(timer:com.twitter.util.Timer,timeout:com.twitter.util.Duration,exc:=%3EThrowable):com.twitter.util.Future[A])

Comment: In order for Future.within to throw a TimeoutException, you have to Await for it. Since Finatra callbacks are called from the Event loop thread, it is never a good idea to Await.

Comment: No, you don't have to `Await`. It will complete with the exception after the time you specify, and the server will return a 500 or whatever you map that exception to.